# Understanding the palindrome code with the logic of split and reverse

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a palindrome code, so I am using the `split` and `reverse` methods. Is my below logic correct? Can I directly use the `reverse` method instead of giving `split` and then `reverse`?

If I give `==` it prints palindrome where as if I give `===` it prints not palindrome. I am a beginner in JS and I am trying to learn.

```
var actualWord = "madam"
var splittedWord = actualWord.split();

console.log("splittedWord---->" + splittedWord);

var reversedWord = splittedWord.reverse();

console.log("reversedWord---->" + reversedWord);
console.log("boolean" + reversedWord === actualWord);

if (reversedWord === actualWord) {
  console.log("palindrome");
} else {
  console.log("not palindrome")
}
```

Comment: why are you splitting ? split function generally splits your string on spaces. but your word does not have any spaces so you get the same word.

Comment: @all  is my logic correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is flawed as `split()` with no parameter to split by returns the original word, which then means that `reverse()` has no effect as you're working on a single element array. You are also attempting to check arrays for equality, which will not work.

To do what you require you need to split by `''` to generate a character array which you can then `reverse()` and `join()` back together to invert the characters of the word. Then you can compare the words to discover if the original was a palindrome. Try this:

```
var actualWord = "madam"
var reverseWord = actualWord.split('').reverse().join('');    
console.log(actualWord, reverseWord);

if (actualWord === reverseWord) {
    console.log(actualWord + " IS a palindrome");
} else {
    console.log(actualWord + " IS NOT a palindrome")
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/u2k8ua5c/)

Taking this a step further you could extract the logic to it's own function and make the string comparison case-insensitive:

```
console.log('madam', isPalindrome('madam'));
console.log('madame', isPalindrome('madame'));
console.log('raceCAR', isPalindrome('raceCAR'));

function isPalindrome(word) {
    var reverseWord = word.split('').reverse().join('');
    return word.toLowerCase() === reverseWord.toLowerCase();
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u2k8ua5c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Several things needed to make your code correct:

- Split the words using `.split("")` not `.split()`
- Create strings from the arrays using `.join("")`
- Put parentheses around the comparator in your "boolean" line, otherwise the "+" will be performed before the "==="

```js
var actualWord = "madam";
var splittedWord = actualWord.split("");
log("splittedWord---->" + splittedWord.join(""));
var reversedWord = splittedWord.reverse();
log("reversedWord---->" + reversedWord.join(""));
log("boolean---->" + (reversedWord.join("") === actualWord));
if (reversedWord.join("") === actualWord) {
  log("palindrome");
} else {
  log("not palindrome")
}

function log(str) {
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p")).innerHTML = str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The == operator will compare for equality after doing any necessary
>   type conversions. The === operator will not do the conversion, so if
>   two values are not the same type === will simply return false. It's
>   this case where === will be faster, and may return a different result
>   than ==. In all other cases performance will be the same.

e.g.-

```
"1" == 1
true
"1" === 1
false
```

in your case, `reversedWord` is an array but `actualWord` is string, hence you get `false` when using `===`, but when you use `==` JS does the necessary type conversion for you and you get `true`.

Comment: `but actualWord is string` Not quite; in the OPs code `actualWord` is an array with a single string element.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the split function before the reverse function because you are referring to a string and not an array.